# OpenGL Lighting with Display Lists

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, jogl

I'm developing some OpenGL game using JOGL library.

When I draw objects regulary, e.g. using GL_QUADS directly in the display method, the scene lighting appears on the object.

However, when I prepare objects in the init method and load using glCallList in the display list, those objects doesn't seem to be affected from the lighting.

To be precise, they are affected in SOME way: altering the materialfv function parameters or the ambient parameters brighten or darken the scene, but the color I'm trying to diffuse is not working (only on the regular drawn objects without lists).

### Code

Here's the lighting code:

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH); // Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); // Black Background
    gl.glClearDepth(1.0f); // Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL); // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    glu = new GLU();
    // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);

    // Light
    float   ambient[] = {0.1f,0.1f,0.1f,1.0f};
    float   diffuse0[] = {1f,0f,0f,1.0f};
    float   diffuse1[] = {0f,0f,1f,1.0f};

    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH); 

    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse0, 0);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);

    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_AMBIENT, ambient, 0);
    gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse1, 0);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT1);

    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);

    // make display lists here...
```

The lighting part of display:

```
// display method...
// apply light
float position0[] = {500, 300, 3500,1.0f};
float position1[] = {500, 300, 500,1.0f};
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT0, GL2.GL_POSITION, position0, 0);
gl.glLightfv(GL2.GL_LIGHT1, GL2.GL_POSITION, position1, 0);
// draw objects directly
// draw objects using glCallLists
```

Here's an example of how I draw regular object in the display method:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(1000, 500, 2000);
    gl.glTexParameteri ( GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_REPEAT );
    gl.glTexParameteri( GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_REPEAT );
    float   material[] = {0.8f,0.8f,0.8f,1.0f};
    gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, material, 0);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Back Face
    gl.glNormal3f(0,0,-1);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    // Top Face
    gl.glNormal3f(0,1,0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    // Bottom Face
    gl.glNormal3f(0,-1,0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Right face
    gl.glNormal3f(1,0,0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Left Face
    gl.glNormal3f(-1,0,0);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glEnd();
    gl.glPopMatrix();
```

[Here's the class I use to load obj files.](http://u.cs.biu.ac.il/~kapaho/CG/Code/WavefrontObjectLoader_DisplayList.java)

I use the method loadWavefrontObjectAsDisplayList which accepts a path to obj file and then returns the list integer.

### Another Edit:

The scene (lamp is being lighten up, crate is not):

[image]

[Link to lamp and crate .obj files.](http://www.filedropper.com/objects)

Comment: You should avoid deprecated OpenGL

Comment: Do yourself a favour and: ditch the Display Lists, keep your geometry in a VBO and use shaders to implement illumination. It's a little bit of work upfront, but pays off big in the long run.

Comment: Do you know how to combine display lists and lighting? I'd rather not ditch the display lists since I have already implemented the logic to use them...

Comment: I agree with @elect and datenwolf. However, in principle, if you use legacy GL, this should also work with display lists. However, it is impossuble to guess what is going on without seeing the code for the display list compilation.

Comment: @derhass Added the class I'm using to load object files. You can use it also and see that it works.

Comment: I still use "legacy" OpenGL and I advise you to stay away from display lists simply because numerous drivers have buggy implementations of this feature even though you want to remain compatible with OpenGL 1.3 hardware. Moreover, there are some more robust WaveFront OBJ loaders in JOGL itself, in JOGL-Utils, in JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation and in JMonkeyEngine, I wouldn't use the one you quote. If you want to stick with display lists, just setup your lights before calling glCallList.

Comment: @gouessej I'm setting up the lights before calling glCallList, however it doesn't work. Maybe the WaveFront objects should have some kind of properties I'm not aware of? Normals, or idk what.
I've added some object and it does gets colored by the diffuse light, but the rest of the objects - not.
All those objects are downloaded from the internet.
I edited the question with how the scene looks, the object that is being lightened correctly and another one which is not. Could you please take a look and see if it lack something?

Comment: We can help you, @Jjang, bringing all the code to current OpenGL. Once you would have lernt the programmable way, you will ask yourself why you didn't do it before. I strongly suggest you to read [this page](http://web.archive.org/web/20140207031129/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/About%20this%20Book.html#d0e30) in order to understand why it is so valuable for you to do that as sooner as you can

Comment: Are you sure that the loader you use correctly handle the MTL file provided with the WaveFront OBJ file?

Comment: @gouessej How do you explain one object is being affected and the others not?
I do not think it handles them correctly though, haven't found evidence that it actually loads the mtl, I even tried deleting them which had no effect. However I do apply glMaterialfv on all the objects with some constant values, so they should have some material...

Comment: float material[] = {0.8f,0.8f,0.8f,1.0f};
            gl.glMaterialfv(GL2.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL2.GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, material, 0);

Comment: So the result wouldn't be "natural" to the object, but at least there has to be some effect on the objects.. but none..

Comment: Do all your objects have correct normals? Does this loader manage them correctly?

Comment: The loader doesn't use the MTL file. If there are no normals in the WaveFront OBJ file, it will fill them with zeros, it won't work in your case.

Comment: @gouessej This seems to work. thanks. added normal to the crate. please post an answer so I can accept. Also, still one last thing doesn't work - the color of the crate doesn't change, only the lamp becomes blue. Any idea?

Comment: You're welcome. How do you compute the normals?

Comment: One normal for every face direction: e.g. normal 0,1,0 for the top of the crate. For other complex objects I'd have to get new files :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normals are probably missing in the WaveFront OBJ file of the crate model.

Then, the OBJ importer that you use generates plain wrong normals whose coordinates are (0, 0, 0), it has no chance to work with the lightning.